Completely changing the meaning of the question body for "How does 'Sign Message' work?"
This question has what seems to be a useful title, and in fact the answer provided does answer that question. However, the body of the question goes off on a tangent that is going to be unhelpful to most people. 
Should the question be rephrased to just ask about what message signing does in the Bitcoin client?

I edited the question that reflects the title better, while still expressing author's doubts that turn out to be irrelevant. I hope that it is more suitable now. If it later turns out that the question should be handled differently, we can always roll back the edit.

I think the message body should be changed to reflect the useful title more strongly, but at the same time try to contain the doubts raised by the question author in the body.
